# SVG image display blurry

Tags: images

When I open SVG files in Emacs they appear blurry. The SVG files themselves are fine (when I open them in Firefox they scale perfectly). My Emacs is compiled with svg support (librsvg), so it should use that for rendering, right?

```
(init-image-library 'svg)
```

returns `t`.

Additionally, I looked at the image overlay properties with `describe-char` and I'm seeing

```
(image :type svg :file "/home/matt/src/blog/org/img/test.svg" :scale 1.726482213438735)
```

which as far as I can tell looks right.

I did notice that `display-mm-width` and height were way too big and I thought that might be giving librsvg a wrong DPI, so I changed them with

```
(setq display-mm-dimensions-alist '(t . (126 . 37)))
```

But that had no effect, even after clearing the image cache.

I also thought maybe imagemagick was getting in the way, so I disabled imagemagick for svg with

```
(add-to-list 'imagemagick-types-inhibit 'SVG)
(imagemagick-register-types)
```

but that also had no effect.

How can I get SVGs to display properly?

I'm using Emacs v28, although I had the same issue with 27 and if I remember correctly, 26 as well. In any event I don't think it's a version issue.

---

Edit:
I was able to get this to work by changing the dvisvgm command options I was using to generate the file. I still don't understand what the issue was because firefox was able to display the SVG fine in either case.

---

Edit 2:
Here's a MWE of the issue. Note the comment above is wrong, I'd simply changed the dvisvgm scale with the -c flag. This hides the issue, but doesn't seem to fix it and messes up image sizes.

I start with a tex document input:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
$a=b+c$
\end{document}
```

then convert it to pdf with

```
pdflatex file.tex
```

and then use dvisvgm with

```
dvisvgm --pdf file.pdf -n -b min -c 1 -o file.svg
```

Here's how it appears in an emacs buffer after several `image-increase-size` commands:
[image]

Here's the same file zoomed to 300% in my browser
[image]

In reference to the first edit, here's what happens when I change the dvisvgm scale (`-c`) to 10
[image]

That looks nice now, but its much larger and when you zoom in you start to see the blurriness reappear
[image]

Comment: could you post the `dvisvgm` parameters you currently have and, if you remember, the previous settings?

Comment: @WojciechGac I've updated the question with more specific information. Let me know if I've omitted any other useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Emacs, documented as issue #1 in [bug report 40845](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=40845). I've copied that portion of the report here for convenience

> Manually scaling an image, as is done for the second image, doesn't re-render the svg: is scales the bitmap-rendered version of it, causing blurriness.

There's a patch in that chain, although it doesn't seem to have been thoroughly tested and has not yet been accepted. I'll update this answer when there's a fix in master.

---

As of August 23, 2020 this is now fixed (see linked bug report for details).

Comment: I still have this problem in Emacs 29.1 built with the `RSVG` library ... however, using the functions in [this post](https://karthinks.com/software/scaling-latex-previews-in-emacs/), I can scale `.svg` LaTeX *previews* fine. However, non-preview `.svg` images don't scale well at all, and appear blurred.