# Getting `dvisvgm` to work with `org-latex-preview`

Tags: org-mode, latex

I am relatively new to Emacs and `org-mode`, and I would like the images displayed by `org-latex-preview` to be `svg`. I am trying to follow the instructions from [this Stack Exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151338/org-latex-preview-is-fuzzy-on-retina-displays).

I have
`(setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'dvisvgm)`
in my configuration file, but the image I'm seeing is definitely not `svg` and rather seems to be the same as what appears with that variable set to `dvipng` instead.

Changing the variable to `imagemagick` does visibly change the image, so I know that Emacs is reading this line of the config file. I can open and view a separate `svg` image with Emacs, so I know that Emacs is able to view `svg` files. Also, when I include `#+OPTIONS: tex:dvisvgm`, the LaTeX is rendered as an `svg`, so I know that Emacs can talk to `dvisvgm`.

I am using:

- Doom with Emacs 26.3
- org-mode 9.4
- MacOS Catalina

Comment: Although the variable should work, it is obsolete: you should use `org-preview-latex-default-process`.  As for whether or not it works, you should check the `ltximg` subdirectory to see whether there is an `org-<mumble>.svg` file there and `cat` the file to make sure that it is an SVG. It may just *look* very much like the corresponding PNG file, fooling you into thinking that it is not SVG.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for your help! You were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is that the images I was looking at *were* svg files (they were not in a `ltximg` subdirectory, but in `~/.emacs.d/.local/cache/org-latex`, maybe something to do with Doom). I learned from [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55305/svg-image-display-blurry) that the blurriness is a known issue in Emacs.

Comment: The image directory is the value of the variable `org-preview-latex-image-directory`. It is `ltximg/` by default, but Doom may very well set it differently indeed.